How to access Data from external module's DAO in some other module's service layer
I have an interface:
public interface UserDao extends Dao <UserEntity> {}

It has one Implementation UserdaoImpl which looks like:
@Component
public class UserDaoImpl extends EsBaseDao < UserEntity > implements UserDao 

Both UserDao and UserDaoImpl are in the com.company.authentication.dataaccess.dao package.
I have a service layer class ScriptValidator.java in some other module com.company.script.core.validator.
In this class, I need to create a method such that I can retrieve a UserEntity, providing a userId I already have.
I tried something like this by adding related dependencies:
package com.company.script.core.vaidator;
    
@Service
public class ScriptValidator {

    @Autowired
    private UserDaoImpl userDaoImpl;
    
    
    private boolean hasPermission (SecurityContext securityContext, String userId) {
    
    UserEntity userEntity= userDaoImpl.read(securitycontext, userId);
    
    // do other stuff with userEntity
    
}

Although it worked as expected, I got comment on this:
"using External Data Access Layer Service class ( which is UserDaImpl ) not supposed to use to retrieve data here". Is this approach not standard, do we have to use some other way to retrieve data from External module DAOs?

So, basically, your code works, but you get some random error message without any context and you expect us to understand/explain why you get it?

@Stultuske actually , there is no error message , I got a review comment "using External Data Access Layer Service class not supposed to use to retrieve data here"... and can say want to ask about approach , if there any other standard than that what I did

so, this is about your companies standards and policies rather than about Java? your company probably has documentation on this.
